# Access the existed actionbar in the activity after come back from the other activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the icon of actionbar in the `MainActivity` when the user comes back from the `Map` activity but I am facing problem that the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` are not being invoked again when I come back from the map activity to the MainActivity. How can I Access the exited acitionbar in the MainActivity?

I tried to accessit  in this way below but without success.

I appretiate any help.

**Map activity:**

```
  public class Map extends ActionBarActivity{
    boolean serviceStatus;
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", serviceStatus);
            editor.commit();        
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
        boolean serviceStatus = true;
createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                GetLLRD.class);
                        intent.putExtra("json_data", json);
                        // getBroadcast; getService
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                                getApplicationContext(), 123, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                System.currentTimeMillis(), 15 * 1000,
                                pendingIntent);
                        // cal.getTimeInMillis(); System.currentTimeMillis()
                        GetLLRD.shouldContinue = true;
}                       startService(intent);

        @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                 super.onStart();
                final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); 
                serviceStatus = (mSharedPreference.getBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", true)); 
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if(serviceStatus){
                actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
            }else{
                actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
            }
        }
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle);
                if(serviceStatus){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
                }else{
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
                }

                return true;
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onPrepareOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    }
```

**GETLLRD IntentSevice class**

```
public class GetLLRD extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                                                        GetLLRD.this, Map.class);
                                                intent1.putExtra("list_data",
                                                        data);
                                                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                                startActivity(intent1);

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from your onPrepareOptionsMenu() function?  It should be being called every time the menu is displayed.

Comment: @Sector95: No it is not being called every time the menu is displayed. I have tried to override it but the Problem was that it is not being called.

Comment: Just to be sure, you were returning true, correct?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Comment: @Sector95: No I am returning `false` from the map activity since I am clicking the icon in the actionbar of the map activity then the value is set to `false` and the Icon changes in the map activity and I want to get the same result in the MainActivity.

Comment: @Sector95: I dont understand why `onPrepareOptionsMenu ()` is not being invoked in my case?

Comment: I meant returning true from the onPrepareOptionsMenu function you had.  Per the documentation, if you return false, the menu is not drawn.

Comment: Oh, I misread what you're doing, you're not changing menu item icons, you're changing the application icon in the action bar.  You need to do some debugging to find out how your "if" statement is functioning.  It could be that your SharedPreference isn't being updated how you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate and onPrepare are invoked only once when the activity is first made. What I assume you are trying to do is have a default icon in the activity, but when you return from the Map activity, the default icon should change to something else?

If thats the case then you need a counter or a boolean to keep track of which parent activity you came from

When switching from Map activity to main activity add extra to the intent to serve as a flag

```
Intent i=new Intent(Map.this, MainActivity.class)
i.putExtra("parent","map");
startActivity(i);
```

And in the MainActivity

Boolean USE_DEFAULT_ICON=true;

```
Intent i=getIntent();
if(i.getBundle!=null) {
if("map".equals(i.getBundle.getExtra("parent").toString())){
USE_DEFAULT_ICON ==false;}
```

and in the onCreate

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(USE_DEFAULT_ICON){
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
}else{
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
}
```

Additionally add this as well

```
    @Override 
protected void onStart() { super.onStart(); invalidateOptionsMenu(); }
```

Comment: @lavan: I am doing the same but in `onStart()` and sharedPrefernces. Please see my updated code above.

Comment: What you are doing is checking the first time the app loads. Shared preferences is loaded when the app is started. To transfer information between activities you have to use intents. Its the most effective way of doing so. In your code I dont see a way in which the app can differenciate between starting MainActivity for the first time or starting it due to an intent from Map Activity which is what sending information in an intent allows for.

Comment: When the user clicks the button in the mainActivity, alarmManager and IntentService `GETLLRD` are triggered to retrieving data from the Server then the MainActivity is being started from the `GETLLRD` class. Therefor, I am using sharedPreferences to pass the boolean value from the Map->Main

Comment: How is the activity being started from the IntentService. Using intents with meta data is far more reliable than shared preferences. Please try using that instead. Alternatively put up more of your code on this or github

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(
              GetLLRD.this, Map.class);
            intent1.putExtra("list_data",
              data);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
              | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent1);

Comment: also I am getting the value in the mainActivity the Problem is I dont know how to set the Icon related to the getting value since onPrepeOptionsMenu is not not being called and I tried it with `item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);` but it does not work.

Comment: After adding `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` to the actionBar in the `onStart()` I noticed that a new icon is displayed left to the app name. My toggle button is at the end of the right. Also `getSupportActionBar()` si the wrong method to get the right actionbar which was set before  in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in the MainActivity

Comment: Change your answer according to theis solution and I will accept it:@Override protected void onStart() { super.onStart(); invalidateOptionsMenu(); }

Answer (score 0):

Try it in onResume of your MainActivity. So that when ever you are back from your MapActivity onResume will be called and thus the following piece of code will work.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(serviceStatus){
            actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
        }else{
            actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am doing the same in `onStart()`.

Comment: just give try using the onResume(). i will come up with better answer if it doesn't works that way.

Comment: why you are calling
Intent i=new Intent(Map.this, MainActivity.class)
i.putExtra("parent","map");
startActivity(i);
just finish the mapactivity and you will endup to land in Mainactivity.
and thus onStart or onResume will be called and you will achieve the icon change setting for actionbar. here as you are calling again startActivity and oncreate will be called on your MainActivity

Comment: @MrPencil: use MapActivity.finish();

Comment: I have tried it in `onResume` but without seccuss. I doent understand yout second comment. The code you have written is in `Varun Agarwal` answer and not my question code!!

Comment: There are 2 ways to switch between activities. One is to use intents which is the CORRECT way of doing so, and the other is relying on the user to use the back navigation and pop activities from the back-stack. To pass meta data between activities you have to use intents which is what I suggested. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @Varun: I have tried it yesterday by sending normal intent to the MainActivity when the user clicks the back button but I always got false in the MainActivity

Comment: @MrPencil: can you please provide your code how you are calling back again from MapActivity to MainActivity.

Comment: @MyPencil Send me the onClickListener code for the back button which the user needs to click to go to the MainActivity.